# The source is not working when use mock in unit test project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

when i use mock concepts to initialize httpcontext.Request.Url in unit test project then source project is not initialized. So it throws null refernce exception. Can you please let me know how to fix this issue?

Ex:

Actual Code

```
class sample

{
    public void sample_method()
    {
        string url=Request.Url.ToString();
    }
}
```

Updated Code for unit test

```
​

class sample: IRequestAttr
{
    private readonly IRequestAttr _attr;

    public sample(IRequestAttr attr)
    {
        _attr=attr;
    }

    public string URL
    {
        return HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
    }

    public void sample_method()
    {
        string url=_attr.URL();
    }
}

public interface IRequestAttr
{
    string URL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
HttpContextBase
```

Create a factory to get your context, in which you could replace the real request with whatever mock you wanted.  More code available on request

Looking at the notes in my own tests, I've bookmarked a blog that explains things quite well
http://www.codethinked.com/Using-SystemWebAbstractions-in-Your-WebForms-Apps